# Is there a way to make a textbox to accept only positive ingegers

Tags: c#

I need to make a textbox to accept only positive integers but I was not successful. 
In my Keypress event in entered this codes:

```
 if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.Back || e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.Delete)
{
    //// To allow  positive integers
}
else
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
//This is used for enter button
int d = Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar);
if (d == 13 && MyExamPeriod_tx.Text != "")
{
}
```

Comment: Make a custom control, derived from TextBox, override `CreateParams` and add `CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams; cp.Style |= ES_NUMBER;`. Where `ES_NUMBER = 0x2000`. Now the TextBox accepts numbers only.

Comment: Please add a tag sepecifying the UI framework you use (WinForms? WPF? ...?) to your question.

Comment: Check out this answer, it answers a very similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21381045/5759850